# Is there a way to query a table in a specific date frequency (for example business days)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, time-series, weekday

Suppose we have a SQL table with entries for different dates such as

`main_table`:

| id (PK) | date (PK) | weekday | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '01-06-2021' | Tue | 20 |
| 1 | '02-06-2021' | Wed | 20 |
| 1 | '04-06-2021' | Fri | 20 |
| 1 | '05-06-2021' | Sat | 20 |
| 1 | '07-06-2021' | Mon | 20 |
| 1 | '08-06-2021' | Tue | 20 |

I would like to retrieve the entries between '30-05-2021' and '07-06-2021'. But the resulting `output_table` table should be in a business days format such that

`output_table`:

| id (PK) | date (PK) | weekday | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '31-05-2021' | Mon | NULL |
| 1 | '01-06-2021' | Tue | 20 |
| 1 | '02-06-2021' | Wed | 20 |
| 1 | '03-06-2021' | Thu | NULL |
| 1 | '04-06-2021' | Fri | 20 |
| 1 | '07-06-2021' | Mon | 20 |
| 1 | '08-06-2021' | Tue | 20 |

If I query the table with a simple `SELECT * WHERE date>='30-05-2021' AND date <= '07-06-2021'` query the following problems would emerge:

- The date '03-06-2021' (a weekday) would be missing.
- There would be no entry for '31-05-2021' (not in main_table).
- The date '05-06-2021' would be retrieved which is, however, no business day (Saturday).

Essentially my idea was to create a business day table (`date_table`) and subsequently use a left join of `main_table` on `date_table`:

```
SELECT main_table.value 
FROM date_table
LEFT JOIN main_table.id ON (date_table.weekly_dates = main_table.date AND main_table.id = 1)
WHERE date_table.weekly_dates >= '30-05-2021'
  AND date_table.weekly_dates <= '07-06-2021'
ORDER BY date_table.weekly_dates
```

However, is there a more elegant solution which does not require the creation of an additional table? Is there a way to directly use it in a SQL query? I also **do not** prefer querying the table and using a programming language to reindex the table (e.g., Python reindex).

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Column date data type?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @jarlh The data type of date is date

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thank you for your feedback. Tag was added

Comment: Use a recursive cte to generate a calendar table. Outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres supports `generate_series()` which makes this pretty simple:

```
select i.id, gs.date, to_char(gs.date, 'Dy') as dow, m.value
from (select distinct id from main_table) i cross join
     generate_series('2021-05-30'::date, '2021-06-07'::date, interval '1 day'
                    ) gs(date) left join
     main_table m
     on m.id = i.id and m.date = gs.date
where to_char(gs.date, 'Dy') not in ('Sat', 'Sun');
```